# Google Map API - cluster marker - How to hide, disable or clear selected or filtered clusterMarkers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

First of all many  thanks & appreciated for any help, advice or suggestion to the above challenges.

In my program there are 2 main parts such as: -
1. Checkbox by category or state.
2. ClusterMarkers by selected category or state

Due to my limitted technical skill and knowledge, I'm having problem to clear, disable or hide the clusterMarker if un-check the checkbox.
U have tried many methods such as: -

```
if ( markerClusterer !== null ) {
   markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
}
```

or 
    var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(clear, 'click', clearClusters);

```
function clearClusters(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
    map.clearOverlays();
}
```

details program & data as follows:-
Program-> [jsfiddle] (jsfiddle.net/39tES) 
Data -> [jsfiddle] (jsfiddle.net/DELus)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want multiple instances.  If you can aggregate your data by state level, you could try making a MarkerClusterer instance for each state / category:

```
var clustererStateOrCat = new MarkerClusterer(mapInstance, markersForStateOrCat, mc_opts);
```

then you could have an object literal that stores the instances:

```
var clusterers[stateOrCategoryName] = clustererStateOrCat;
```

Then you could just detect what state / category was clicked, and remove / draw the markers for just that specific entity.